# Cordova - cordova-plugin-file - how to save and locate file later

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am trying to make some code, where I record a sound using the Cordova media api, and then I need to locate that file and use it.
If I do it like this

```
            var src = "voice_recording.mp3";
            media = new Media(src,

                function() {
                    alert("recordAudio():Audio Success");
                    //media.stopRecord();
                },

                function(err) {
                    alert("recordAudio():Audio Error: "+ err.code);
                }
            );
            media.startRecord();
```

the file gets saved in the device Internal storage, at the top directory.
Now if I try to locate it like this

```
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL("voice_recording.mp3", 

            function (ee) {
                // asd
                debugger;
                alert(ee.message);
            },

            function (ee) {
                // asd
                debugger;
                alert(ee.message);
            }
        );
```

I keep getting errors and this is hard to debug.

How can I make it to save in some directory related to the app itself, and how do I locate the file later?

Answer (score 0):

Try saving your media to `cdvfile://localhost/persistent/voice_recording.mp3`. This will ensure that the file is in a persistent location while also easily retrievable by your later code.

As for debugging, enable debugging on your device and use Chrome (Android)/Safari (iOS) to debug your app. Both let you see the Javascript console and interact with your app as it is running.